# fancyBox2 で写真をポップアップすると、 `Please try again later.` エラーが表示される

Tags: javascript, jquery

fancyBox2 で写真をポップアップさせたいのですが、`The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.` という文章が出てしまいます。

何が間違えているのでしょうか？？

僕が現状書いているプログラムは以下のとおりです。
なお、 DreamWeaver CS6 の可変グリッドを使いウェブサイトを作っております。

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="we are web maker" />
<meta name="keywords" content="we are">
<meta name="robots" content="ALL">
<title> Welcome to Web Site　</title>

<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="cotte_index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ADFFE9;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancyapps-fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css">


<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancyapps-fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<script src="respond.min.js"></script>


<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/alike:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->


<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
</script>


</head>

  <body>


    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

     <div class="blank">

       <div id="all_contents">

       <div id="image-home">
         <p><img src="images/home_picture_png.png"></p>
       </div>

       <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo-web.png"></div>



        <nav id="navi" class="fluid ">

                <ul id="menu" class="fluid fluidList ">

                        <li class="fluid menu_list" id="home_btn"><a href="1.html">1</a></li> 

                        <li class="fluid menu_list " id="2_btn"><a href="2.html">2</a></li>

                        <li class="fluid menu_list" id="3_btn"><a href="3.html">3</a></li>

                        <li class="fluid menu_list" id="4_btn"><a href="4.html">4</a></li>

                        <li class="fluid menu_list" id="5_btn"><a href="5">5</a></li>

                        <li class="fluid menu_list " id="6_btn"><a href="6">6</a></li>

                </ul>
        </nav>

        <h2>We are</h2>

                           <a class="fancybox" href="stylist_pt/aa1.png" data-fancybox-group="group" title=""><img src="stylist_pt/aa2.png" alt="" /></a>

        <footer id="footer" class="fluid ">Copyright© 2014 we are web maker . All Rights Reserved.</footer>

    </div><!--all_contents end-->
     </div><!--blank end-->
  </div><!--end gridcontainer clearfix-->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a class="fancybox" href="stylist_pt/aa1.png" data-fancybox-group="group" title="">
    <img src="stylist_pt/aa2.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

この部分を

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8614/15993952806_52bd5e4798_b.jpg" title="Glowing Oak (Keartona)">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8614/15993952806_52bd5e4798_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

こうしただけで動作が確認できました。

アップロード先で画像のURLを指定して画像のみ表示できますか？
もしくは拡張子やファイル名が大文字になっていませんか？

Comment: ご指摘のように、ウェブにあるいろんなサイトや、そのサイトにあるリンク画像をHtｍｌに貼り付けていろいろやってみると、成功しました。
そして、画像のフォルダはアップロードされていたのですが、内容がアップロードされておらず、それで、うまくいかないということがわかりました。
そして、現在うまくいっています。
適切なご指示に感謝いたします

Answer (score 2):

画像ファイルが期待された URL に存在しない可能性があります。以下の部分:

```
<h2>We are</h2>
<a class="fancybox" href="stylist_pt/aa1.png" data-fancybox-group="group" title="">
  <img src="stylist_pt/aa2.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

この記述は、「 *最初に画像 `stylist_pt/aa2.png` を表示しておいて、クリックされたときに、 画像 `stylist_pt/aa1.png` を拡大表示する指定* 」です。拡大表示するべき画像を取得しようとしたときに、 404 エラーが返っていると `The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.` が表示されます。ですので、質問の場合も単純に、 `stylist_pt/aa1.png` にファイルが存在しないのではないでしょうか。

直接 URL にアドレスを指定して確認してみてください。ページを閲覧するのに:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/site/sample.html`

にアクセスしていたとすれば:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/site/stylist_pt/aa1.png`

が必要な画像の URL になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

ライブビューでは正常に動いておりますし、フォルダの中に、確かに画像は存在しております。

どういうことなのでしょうか？？
アクセスを変えなければ動かないものなのでしょうか？

ともかくやってみます

Comment: やってみましたが動きません。。
ローカルでは動いているのですが、アップロードしてグーグルでみるとやっぱり同じ様に「please try」を言われてしまいます。

何が原因なのかさっぱりです・・

Comment: そうですか・・・私は自分のサーバに、HTMLをアップロードしたのですが無事に画像を見ることができてしまいました。エラーがでるパターンは画像の読み込み失敗だけでしたのでこの回答に落ち着いています。「アップロードしてグーグルでみると」とおっしゃられましたが、どこに、どのようにページをアップロードされていますか？特殊なサーバを使用されているのではないかという気がしてきました。

Comment: ご協力ありがとうございます。
ご指摘どおり、画像のフォルダーの問題でした。。。
dreamweaver内でアップロードしていて、「すべてのファイルをアップロード」としていたのですが、どういうわけか、僕が広げたい写真がサーバー側にアップロードされておらず、それでリクエストができない状況でした。
ともかく、問題点をご指摘くださったので、問題を探すことができました。
助かりました！

Comment: 質問にソースコードを張ってくれていたので、fancyBox2 を試しやすかったですよ。あとは Chrome をお使いであれば、 `Ctrl+Shift+I` で出てくるウィンドウの `Console`/`Network` タブを見る癖をつけると気付きやすいです。